# Windows command line scripting with Ruby. #each loop behaving unexpectedly

Tags: ruby, windows

I'm expecting multiple machines to close processes and restart a `.bat` file (I'm scripting Windows.) It only works for the first machine.

```
nodes = (1234..1235).to_a
nodes.map! { |node| "pc" + node.to_s }
apps_to_close = ["iexplore.exe", "powershell.exe", "ruby.exe", "chrome.exe", 
  "cmd.exe", "taskhost.exe", "git.exe", "git-tfs.exe"]

def process_node(apps_to_close, node)
  begin
     apps_to_close.each do |app|
      `taskkill.exe /S #{node} /U joe_user /P joe_pass /IM #{app} /F`
    end
     `@powershell cmdkey.exe /add:#{node} /user:joe_user /pass:joe_pass; 
      schtasks /RUN /TN "start_my_sched_task" /s "#{node}"`
  rescue
    puts "#{node} could not be restarted"
  end
end

nodes.each do |node|
  process_node(apps_to_close, node)
end
```

Comment: Are you getting an error message? If so, what error message did you get?

Comment: No error message. It just does not close apps or start my scheduled tasks for any pc past the first. It never goes to the rescue either.

Comment: Try putting a `puts node` in the loop and make sure all of the nodes are being looped through.

Comment: You need to get errors of some kind or there's no way of knowing what's wrong here. You could start by killing off these ugly back-tick-style command executions and replace that with `system('taskill.exe', '/S', node, '/U', 'joe_user', ...)` where you can capture the result of that command. You can also use [`popen3`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.4.0/Open3.html) to capture any diagnostic output that might be relevant.

Comment: I did have a version with `popen3`. It tried to print the stderr in the rescue. it never did. I did not do `puts node`, but I debugged. It only went through the first node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it:

```
nodes = (1234..1235).to_a
nodes.map! { |node| "pc" + node.to_s }
apps_to_close = ["iexplore.exe", "powershell.exe", "ruby.exe", "chrome.exe", 
  "cmd.exe", "taskhost.exe", "git.exe", "git-tfs.exe"]

def process_node(apps_to_close, node)
  begin
     apps_to_close.each do |app|
      `taskkill.exe /S #{node} /U joe_user /P joe_pass /IM #{app} /F`
    end
     Process.spawn("@powershell cmdkey.exe /add:#{node} /user:joe_user /pass:joe_pass; 
      schtasks /RUN /TN \"start_my_sched_task\" /s \"#{node}\"")
  rescue
    puts "#{node} could not be restarted"
  end
end

nodes.each do |node|
  process_node(apps_to_close, node)
end
```